# Jquery animate an "array object"

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Apologies in advance if this question is trivial but being new to scripting, I was wondering how can I ".finish()" a currently executing animation that is NOT called on a DOM element (such as a div element) but rather the animation was called on an array object?

```
$({countNum: 0 }).animate( {countNum: 100 }, {
  duration: 5000... (code continues)
```

Here's an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/AndreasEvans/smzcf1f4/9/

Many thanks in anticipation of your kind responce

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code? You can only animate DOM elements. Animating an object does not make sense as it wont have any visible effect

Comment: Not 100% true, the code works fine and animates any number of DOM elements, changes colours as they go through 50% & 80% from Green to Amber to Red and shows % utilisation (again text colour animated)...but the main purpose of this question is to be able to .finish() the animation if the user clicks a button and since I am not doing $("#progressBar").animate(.... code, I can't refer to the "object" by "name" so can't do $("#progressBar").finish()...

Comment: Hmm maybe i'm not 100% understanding your issue here then. If you could do a jsfiddle that shows your issue maybe i'll be able to help out.

Comment: Well that was fun...what a great site JSFiddle is.  I've subscribed and typed in a "heavily" edited version of the code to illustrate what I mean. https://jsfiddle.net/AndreasEvans/smzcf1f4/4/  In the version I use, there are dozens of users and there's more going on too...but I hope this helps as I am very keen to better understand the .animate() method and that means all it's various modes of use.

Comment: Posted an answer for you, I hope that it makes sense and helps!

Comment: FANTASTIC...problem solved thank you.  $(this)...was the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so here's a solution for you:

Firstly add an html input button:

```
<input id="stop-animation" type="button" value="stop loader" />
```

Then create a global variable that can be used to check whether the animation needs to stop. Also bind a click event to your button that sets the value of this variable to true.

```
var stopAnimation = false;
$('#stop-animation').click(function(){
    stopAnimation = true;
});
```

In the step callback function of animate then put the following line

```
if(stopAnimation){
    $(this).stop( true, true );
}
```

The `$(this).stop( true, true );` is explained below.

> The first true clears the queue and the last true jumps to the end of
>   the animation queue, effectively ending the animation.

Here's an example, click the stop loader button to stop the loader.

https://jsfiddle.net/smzcf1f4/6/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow...simple when you know how and you clearly do.  

Thank you so much Jako...very much appreciated.  $(this)...I should have known!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you will have get rid of *anonymous* object and rather give it a name. Then, accessing it to `stop();` it on a button click becomes easy.

***Snippet:***

```js
var myObject = {count: 0};
var myButton = document.querySelector('input');
myButton.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick, false);
$(myObject).animate({count: '100'}, {progress: onProgress, duration: 4000});
function onButtonClick(){ $(myObject).stop(true, true); } // or use finish(); if you would like.
function onProgress(){ document.querySelector('div').innerText = myObject.count; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<input type="button" value="Stop" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much as your answer helps to explain much more about the "structure" of JS than just my question and it will help me develop better code in the future.